# Change color of text in mapnik osm xml

Tags: xml, rendering, openstreetmap, mapnik

I am trying to change the color of the text in mapnik xml. The color is stored in the database and it can be available by [fill_color].

How can I set 'fill'?

```
<TextSymbolizer dy="10" size="10" wrap-width="30" line-spacing="-1.5" fill=??? fontset-name="fontset-0" halo-radius="1" halo-fill="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)" placement="interior"><![CDATA[name]]></TextSymbolizer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply use:

```
fill="[fill_color]"
```